# Dynamic data in  Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Has anyone used the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) Javascript charting library? 
I have a few questions about it:

- Does it support dynamic data? In other words, if I plot a chart and then want to update the data displayed on the chart, do I need to completely unload the chart and start over? Or can I update the chart's data in-place?
- Is there a way to hide grid lines on line/bar charts?
- The documentation on the site looks a bit thin. Are there any more resources online for these charts?

Comment: Highcharts has an impressive website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new call to

```
new Highcharts.Chart(...)
```

should do the trick. The docs are quite complete, but maybe too young to be helpful enough. And the support may be better with the commercial license. Did you check other libs like [Flotr](http://code.google.com/p/flotr/) ?

Answer (score 7):

The [Highcharts forum](http://highslide.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=9) is pretty active and you should be able to find the answers to most of your questions there.

I've used Highcharts and love the interface and the charts that it produces.

Yes, Highcharts allows you to dynamically modify your charts and you shouldn't have to unload the chart in order to add new series data.  [Here's](http://highcharts.com/demo/?example=dynamic-click-to-add&theme=default) an example to add new data points to an existing series, and check out [Chart.addSeries()](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart-object) if you want to add a whole new series.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - it supports things you mentioned. Here's the `sample code` http://jsfiddle.net/sdorzak/HsWF2/

also the documentation looks 'thin' but it's pretty good. I'm starting to discover that you can really do a lot with these charts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Flot.js](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)?  It relies on JQuery.  Very nice, very easy, lightweight, and **open source**.